# Clients won't work regular in socket application in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple chat application works on my localhost.
It works okay on the CMD but whenever I try to build it on GUI, errors the mistakes don't leave me alone.
[image]

You see? The first application I'm open works as expected, but when I attempt to open another application, the second application that I'm open sends data to the first application.

**gui**

```
package program;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

public class gui
{
    private boolean basladi=false;
    Client client;
    server _server;
    JFrame pencere;
    JButton button;
    static JTextArea area;
    JTextField type;
    public gui(){

        pencere = new JFrame("oxChat");
        pencere.setSize(640,480);
        pencere.setLayout(null);
        button = new JButton("gönder");
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(!basladi){
                    basladi=true;
                    client = new Client("127.0.0.1",4000);
                }else{
                    client.sendData(type.getText());
                }
            }
        });
        area = new JTextArea();
        type = new JTextField();
        pencere.add(type);
        pencere.add(area);
        pencere.add(button);
        area.setBounds(0,0,640,350);
        type.setBounds(0,370,640,25);
        button.setBounds(640/2-80/2,400,80,30);
        pencere.setVisible(true);
        pencere.setResizable(false);
        pencere.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        _server = new server();
        _server.start(4000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        gui app = new gui();
    }

}
```

**client**

```
package program;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client
{
    // initialize socket and input output streams
    private Socket socket        = null;
    private DataInputStream input = null;
    private DataOutputStream out     = null;

    // constructor to put ip address and port
    public Client(String address, int port)
    {
        // establish a connection
        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            System.out.println("Connected");

            // takes input from terminal
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            // sends output to the socket
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException u)
        {
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }

    void sendData(String data){
        try{
            out.writeUTF(data);
        }catch(IOException i)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**server**

```
package program;

// A Java program for a Server
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server
{
    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket server;
    public static   String data;
    // constructor with port
    public void start(int port){
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true){
                socket = server.accept();
                new Thread (new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start();
            }
        }catch(IOException i){

        }
    }
}

class ConnectionHandler extends Thread{
    gui app;
    private String data;
    private Socket       socket = null;
    private DataInputStream in   = null;
    private DataOutputStream out     = null;
    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket){
        this.socket=socket;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String line = "";

            // reads message from client until "Over" is sent
            while (!line.equals("Over"))
            {
                try
                {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    app.area.append(line+"\n");
                }
                catch(IOException i)
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            // close connection
            socket.close();
            in.close();
        }
        catch(IOException i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    public String getServerData(){
        return  data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `app.area.append(line+"\n");` You should do that in the AWT event thread. Use `String newline = line; EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> app.area.append(newline+"\n"));`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to java, I know the algorithm to build server-client application but I can't build it on GUI because I don't have enough knowledge on Java.I need step by step how to.

Comment: If you don't have an gui experience, why don't you start with basic tutorials that give you nice, complete, well explained examples? Gui programming is complicated. Learning it via trial and error does not work for such topics!

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code again, it just happens by chance that it works for the first instance.

Let's walk through the code to see what's happening:

In `gui.java`, you create a new server:

```
_server = new server();
_server.start(4000);
```

Which in turn will try to listen on the given port:

```
server = new ServerSocket(port);
```

This won't obviously work for the second instance, but you catch the resulting `IOException` and just throw it away:

```
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true) {
            socket = server.accept();
            new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socket)).start();
        }
    } catch(IOException i) {
         // Please do something here
    }
```

So, the second instance won't have a server that is listing on the port.
You shouldn't just ignore an exception, but that's a different problem.
So you only have one server running. Which is fine. One server, many clients.

There is an other problem in the method above, which is that this method will never return (except if it could not bind to the port).

Now, when a client sends you data, the server will receive it here:

```
while (!line.equals("Over")) {
    try {
        line = in.readUTF();
        app.area.append(line+"\n");
    } catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The only thing you do with the received data is to add it to the gui.
Other clients won't see this message.
You have to send the data to all other clients. Which requires you to keep a list of all connected clients around.

And that's the point where things get complicated:
You have shared mutable state that is accessed by more than one thread.
Which means you have to use synchronization.

Ok, let's do that:

- Add a `List<ConnectionHandler>` to your server class:

  ```
  List<ConnectionHandler> clients = new ArrayList<>();
  ```
- And for good measure, a lock:

  ```
  Object lock = new Object();
  ```
- Then we need to add any new connected client to that list:

  ```
  socket = server.accept();
  ConnectionHandler client = new ConnectionHandler(this, socket)
  synchronized (lock) {
      clients.add(client);
  }
  new Thread(client).start();
  ```
- Now we just need a method to distribute all the incoming messages in the server class:

  ```
  void distributeMessage(String message) {
      List<ConnectionHandler> clientsCopy;
      synchronized (lock) {
          clientsCopy = new ArrayList<>(clients);
      }
      for (ConnectionHandler client : clientsCopy) {
          client.sendMessage(message);
      }
  }
  ```
- Now we need to change the ConnectionHandler, and we start by cleaning up the fields:

  ```
  private Socket socket;
  private DataInputStream in;
  private DataOutputStream out;
  private server server;
  ```

  Those are all the fields that we need.
- Next we need to change the constructor of this class:

  ```
  public ConnectionHandler(server server, Socket socket) {
      this.server = server;
      this.socket = socket;
      this.in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
      this.out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
  }
  ```

  All fields should be initialized in the constructor if possible.
- Then we have to add our new `sendMessage(String message)` method:

  ```
  public void sendMessage(String message) {
      try {
          out.writeUTF(message);
          out.flush();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO: Here you HAVE to check if the connection was closed
          // And if it was closed, call a method in the server class to
          // remove this client.
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```
- Almost done. Now the clients actually need to listen to the message they receive. I leave it to you to do that. It's basically the same as you did in your server before.

Comment: Hi,I did that but problems remain.Here is the picture https://pasteboard.co/IEe8pv4.png